# Merge two texts in javascript

Tags: javascript, text, merge, diff

What's the best way to merge two texts in javascript, without any need for user interaction in conflicts, it should be completely silent. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Without far more detail explaining what you actually want to do, this is the best I can offer: `newtext = text1 + text2;`

Comment: No, that's not what I want to do. To clarify, I want kind of a diff/merge thing I guess, where it will combine the two texts.

Comment: The question is unclear. Is there any relationship between user interaction and merging two texts?

Comment: You really, really need to clarify the question or it will be closed for being too ambiguous and unclear what is being asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something which can generate a diff which has been implemented in JS.  You may want to look into [jsdiff](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/).

Comment: How does generating a diff ever result in a conflict?  This sounds like a partial answer, at best.  But then again, the question is so vague/incomplete, it's impossible to be sure.